# Test with Mongodb and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

I have a Typescript project that uses mongodb-memory-server as a db for tests; I upgraded the version of this library from "6.9.6" to "8.0.4" and now I have many errors like this:

```
export async function findPromise<T>(
    collection: string,
    findParams: Query<T>, // must replace with Query<mongo.Document>,
    sort?: Sort,
    proxy = _mongoProxy
): Promise<Array<T & { _id: mongo.ObjectId }>> {
    return proxy
        .connect()
        .then((db: mongo.Db) => db.collection(collection))
        .then((c: mongo.Collection) =>
            c
                .find(findParams)
                .sort(sort || {})
                .toArray()
        )
        .then(async (elements: T[]) => { // elements: Query<mongo.Document>[]
            await proxy.close();
            return elements as Array<T & { _id: mongo.ObjectId }>;
        })
        .catch(
            /* istanbul ignore next */
            async (err) => {
                await proxy.close(true);
                _log.error({ error: err }, "ERROR");
                return [] as Array<T & { _id: mongo.ObjectId }>;
            }
        );
}
```

Query is defined as

```
export type Query<T> = mongo.Filter<T>;
```

The error is:

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(filter: Filter<Document>, options?: FindOptions<Document> | undefined): FindCursor<WithId<Document>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Query<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<Document>'.
      Type 'Query<T>' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: any; _id?: Condition<ObjectId> | undefined; }'.
        Types of property '_id' are incompatible.
          Type 'Condition<WithId<T>["_id"]> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ObjectId> | undefined'.
            Type 'AlternativeType<WithId<T>["_id"]>' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ObjectId> | undefined'.
              Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ObjectId> | undefined'.
                Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
                  Type 'AlternativeType<EnhancedOmit<T, "_id">["_id"] & InferIdType<T>>' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ObjectId> | undefined'.
                    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ObjectId> | undefined'.
                      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
                        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ObjectId> | undefined'.
                          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
                            Type 'AlternativeType<EnhancedOmit<T, "_id">["_id"] & InferIdType<T>>' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
                              Type 'AlternativeType<WithId<T>["_id"]>' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
                                Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
                                  Type 'AlternativeType<EnhancedOmit<T, "_id">["_id"] & InferIdType<T>>' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
                                    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
                                      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FilterOperators<ObjectId>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(filter: Filter<Document>, options?: FindOptions<Document> | undefined): FindCursor<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Query<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<Document>'.

276                 .find(findParams)
```

How can I fix them? I have also updated Typescript; node types, mongodb client but with no success.

UPDATE: I have to replace Query<T> with Query<mongo.Document>, but why???

Comment: There's a closing parenthesis `)` missing somewhere at the end. Code isn't closed

Comment: I have updated the question, thanks.

Comment: It looks like `findParams: Query<T>` has been updated in the new version with `findParams: Filter<Document>`, that's probably a breaking change between 6.9 to 8.0. The documentation probably addresses this